# How to manually kick players in new Unity Input System

Tags: unity, c#, multiplayer

Using the new Unity `PlayerInputManager`, I'm trying to create a page in the pause menu of the game where players can remove other players from the game.  It's a split-screen game, and it seems to handle kicking the last player (i.e. if there were three players, kicking the third) just fine.

However, if we have three players and we destroy the `gameobject` for player two, it seems like the player index and the screen index of player three do not automatically adjust, and the screen remains split three ways.  Here's some of the code I've tried:

```
public void KickPlayer(int i)
    {

      PlayerInput.Destroy(players[i]);
      players[i] = null;
      for (int j = i; j < 4; j++)
      {
          if (j+1 == 4 || players[j+1] == null)
          {
              players[j] = null;
          } else
          {
              players[j] = players[j + 1];
              players[j + 1] = null;
              PlayerInput pi = players[j].GetComponent<PlayerInput>();
              PlayerInput.Instantiate(players[j], j, pi.currentControlScheme, pi.splitScreenIndex-1, pi.devices.ToArray());
              PlayerInput.Destroy(players[j + 1]);
          }
      }
}
```

Although this code looks like it should rearrange and re-assign the split-screen, what I end up with when I spawn in three players and try to kick player two is player 0 with split-screen index 0, then there suddenly are three other players, player 1, 2, and a second copy of player 2 all sharing split-screen index 2.

What would be the best way to go about this?  Is there a way to reassign player index and split-screen index?